# Is this correct answer for listing sample space elements?

Tags: probability

[image]

The answer for part (a) is simple. For the part (b), the author states this answer

$$
S = \{(x,y) | 1 \leq x, y \leq 6 \}
$$
But I feel this is incorrect. My answer is

$$
S = \{ (x,y) | 1 \leq x \leq 6, 1 \leq y \leq 6, x \in \mathbb{N}, y \in \mathbb{N} \}
$$

What do you think?

Comment: I don't know what "the rule method" is, but why do you think those two sets are different?

Comment: Please don't post unsearchable pictures of text.  Instead, typeset (using *MathJax*).

Comment: @innerproduct  for the author's answer, $x$ has no upper bound and it didn't state for which number group $x$ belongs to. This is also same for $y$.

Comment: @innerproduct the rule method basically is to state the sample space in a statement or equation rather than explicitly listing the elements.

Comment: If you interpret the $","$ as making them distinct inequalities, then yes it is incorrect. For some reason I interpreted it as saying both $x$ and $y$ are between $1$ and $6$.

Comment: @innerproduct you may be right about it but still we don't know for which number group $(x,y)$ belong to.

Comment: Technically you are right, that it doesn't say which $\textit{set}$ (I would refrain from using the word "group" here because that has it's own technical definition) the elements belong to. So in that regard your answer is better. Note that it's acceptable to just write $x,y \in \mathbb{N}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your answer is clearer. Alternatively, you could write

\begin{align}
S&=\{(x,y)\in \mathbb{N}^2 \,|\, 1\leq x\leq 6, 1\leq y\leq 6\}.\\
\end{align}